# Like a quine, but not

Tags: popularity-contest, quine, underhanded

Very simple, write a program that at first glance appears to be a quine, but is not. Upon running, the program actually prints the source to a real quine, obviously distinct from the original program in some way, preferably creative, but since this is a popularity contest, the answer with the most upvotes wins.

[Standard Loopholes which are no longer funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: Can I allow requiring specific input in my answer, or does my program have to work regardless of input?

Comment: I think it has to work regardless of the input.

Comment: Why does this question have so many dislikes?

Comment: @loovjo I have no idea. Vague? Open ended?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an [underhanded] challenge, which was on-topic a year ago, but is now off-topic by [community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8326/31716).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## CJam

```
{"_~"}_~
```

Well, whether this *looks* like a real quine to you depends on whether you're used to CJam or GolfScript, but anyway, it looks like and prints the standard quine:

```
{"_~"}_~
```

Wait, isn't that the same thing?

> Nope, there's a space at the end of the first code. I believe the same thing would work in almost any language with almost any quine.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%22_~%22%7D_~%20)

Comment: CJam. What can it do? Everything, apparently...

Answer (score 12):

## [H9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/H9+)

```
"Hello, world!"
```

It's easy: In H9+, anything other than H, 9, or + is ignored, and therefore, this is a quine. Or is it?

> Nope. H actually outputs `Hello, world!`, with no quotes.

Answer (score 9):

## Python

```python
s="s=%r\nprint(s%%s)"
print(s%s)
```

Explanation:

> The output actually has single quotes instead of double quotes.

[**Try it here**](http://repl.it/nqE)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica

This one can be quite tricky to newer users.

```
Function[Print[StringJoin[ToString[FullForm[#0]], "[];"]]][];
```

Explanation:

> Some people might not notice the `#0` as not being part of the `FullForm`. In the output, it is replaced with `Slot[0]`. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell

Recursion can be tricky at times.

```haskell
let s = "let s = " ++ show s ++ " in putStrLn s" in putStrLn s
```

---

> This actually outputs the same as '`s = "let s = " ++ show s in putStrLn s`', namely '`let s = "let s = \"let s = \\\"let s = \\\\\\\"let s = \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"let s = \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"...`'

---

> Basically, Haskell is trying to let `s` be equal to itself, with `let s =` appended to it, and escaping the string.

---

> Obviously, in order to escape `"` you need `\"`, and in order to escape `\` you get `\\`, which is how the long stream of backslashes is formed.